# React doesn't render CSS styles

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, nodemon

I faced a problem with React CSS. My server is picking up, but my CSS properties are not working on my component. How can I fix this problem? I tried many ways to figure it out but I didn't get a good response.

`App.js` file codes:

```
import styles from "./App.module.css";
import { ReactDOM } from "react";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { init, subscribe } from "./socketApi";
import Palatte from "./components/Palatte";

function App() {
  const [activeColor, setActiveColor] = useState("#282c34");

  useEffect(() => {
    init();

    subscribe((color) => {
      setActiveColor(color);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ backgroundColor: activeColor }}>
      <h1>{activeColor}</h1>
      <Palatte activeColor={activeColor} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

CSS file codes:

```
.App {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.palette {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.palette button {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

I tried many ways to fix it but I didn't get a solution.

[Current view on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q4GA.png)

Comment: It looks like you're using CSS modules, so there won't be a global class named "App", instead it will be renamed to be unique to the component. You probably want `div className={styles.App}`. And you don't show us how `Palatte` is used, but you probably need to do the same thing in that component. However you created your app (which you don't tell us) - look up how to add global styles to it if you want to use the classname as a string. In the future you should start using the Chrome element inspector to look at how styles are applied to your elements.

Comment: Hi, here is file source where I downloaded this code. 
 I tried on my macbook a few minutes ago and I faced again same problem. I never changed any codes in this repository. Where is the problem ? 
 https://github.com/Kodluyoruz/taskforce/tree/react-patika/react-patika/realtime/realtime-colors

Answer (score 1):

When you tried importing the CSS styles, you did `import ... from ...` whereas you should be doing `import ./App.module.css` only, that's because you're trying to `import from` from a CSS file, which isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `className="App"` to `className={styles.App}`.